# Formdata not being sent through to NodeJS backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, axios, form-data

I have a function that should send FormData as an axios.post call to my api. It gets activated with a press of a button

```js
  const sendCard = (card) => {
    debugger;
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append("itemID", itemID);
    data.append("comment", comment);
    data.append("dateStart", dates[0]);
    data.append("dateEnd", dates[1]);
    data.append("qtyWant", qtyWant);
    requestBooking(data);
  };
```

and here is the axios part:

```js
export const requestBooking = async (data) => {
  return await api
    .post(`/booking/request`, data)
    .then((data) => {
      return "DONE!";
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.response.data);
    });
};
```

the api is an import from a config.js file, and everything there works with all the other aspects of my website.

I have another FormData object being posted into the api, and that one works properly, even though there is no differences at all...

Here is the accepting function on the back end

```js
  app.post(
    "/api/booking/request",
    request
  );

exports.request = (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send("Reached");
};
```

where req.body is just an empty object ({})

This all seems like it should work. And I don't know what am I missing

Comment: "I have another FormData object being posted into the api, and that one works properly" — Please provide a [mcve] showing both routes and the body parsing middleware you are using (in context because the order matters).

Comment: Update Axios to the latest version - 0.27.2